# Issue with getting a special attribute in XPath

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath

I'm trying to change the `xml:lang` attribute value, from `<section>` however it gives me an error, probably because of the ":"

I've also tried to get the text just to check but it also makes an error:

```
Debug.WriteLine(xml.SelectSingleNode("/section/@xml:lang").InnerText)
```

I've also tried with Linq but it makes also an error...

Here is beginning of my XML file if it can help:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<section xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xmlns:ns5="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" xmlns:d="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" audience="notxml" xml:id="EBLTE00BLT501" remap="EBLTE00BLT501-Tuyaux_BLUTOP_dn75-160" version="5.0" xml:lang="fr" role="fiche">

  <title>Tubo BLUTOP BioZinalium (fabrico para expedição em contentor)</title>

    [...]
```

Thank you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify the namespace:

```
var manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
manager.AddNamespace("ns", "http://docbook.org/ns/docbook");

var lang = xml.SelectSingleNode("/ns:section/@xml:lang", manager);
lang.InnerText = "en";
```

Also you can obtain it more simply:

```
var lang = xml.DocumentElement.Attributes["xml:lang"];
lang.InnerText = "en";
```

Comment: Works so well !! Thank you